# How can I do Spring Security authentication from within a JSF form

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I created a simple JSF login page, and I'm trying to integrate it with spring security.

Here is the form element from **login.xhtml**

```
    <h:form>

     <h:outputLabel value="User Id:" for="userId"/>

     <h:inputText id="j_username" label="User Id"
     required="true"   value="#{loginBean.name}" >

     </h:inputText>

     <h:outputLabel value="Password: "  for ="password"/>

     <h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />

     <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{j_spring_security_check}" />

 </h:form>
```

But the rendered html page has something like the below. Take a look at the form action and the input tag's names

***The form element***

```
  <form id="j_idt6" name="j_idt6" method="post" 
    action="/jsfproject2/faces/login.xhtml"
       enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

***And the input tags***

```
   User Id:</label><input id="j_idt6:j_username" type="text"
     name="j_idt6:j_username" />
```

**Now I want form action to be `/j_spring_security_check` and input boxes to be 'j_username' and `j_password`**

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two options for Spring Security to work.

### Use `prependId="false"` on a JSF form

As `<h:form>` is a naming container, it prepends id of its children with the specified `id`, or the autogenerated id, so as Spring Security expects ids to remain unchainged, just don't prepend the ids:

```
 <h:form prependId="false">
     <h:outputLabel value="User Id: " for="userId" />
     <h:inputText id="j_username" label="User Id" required="true" value="#{loginBean.name}" />
     <h:outputLabel value="Password: "  for ="password" />
     <h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
     <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
</h:form>
```

Note that `#{j_spring_security_check}` is a wrong action method: it needs to be `#{loginBean.login}` with the following contents:

```
public String login() {
    //do any job with the associated values that you've got from the user, like persisting attempted login, etc.
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext extenalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest)extenalContext.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");
    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)extenalContext.getRequest(), (ServletResponse)extenalContext.getResponse());
    facesContext.responseComplete();
    return null;
}
```

Basically, all you need to do is dispatch to `/j_spring_security_check` and have `j_username` and `j_password` as request parameters.

### Use plain HTML form

Basically, there's no particular need to mess with JSF form on this issue, in case you don't need to do some extra things apart from authentication, and plain HTML form is sufficient for Spring Security to do its job.

```
<form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <label for="j_username">User Id: </label>
    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" />
    <label for="j_password">Password: </label>
    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @MaksymDemidas You really don't need to overcomplicate in case you don't need the functionality. It's like using Web frameworks' tags all around instead of, say, plain `div`s.

Comment: Note: When there is no h:form and no backing bean, the required-Attribute on the inputs won't work, as far as I know. Just in case one wants to check for empty inputs beforehand.

Comment: I humbly think that there is need to complicate things, because I (for instance) need to translate the login page into several languages. Doing that with html is cumbersome and falls apart from the neat resources jsf provides.

Comment: @Raul That's exactly the thing that was meant in the answer: if the only thing you need is authentication, then you can use vanilla HTML form. But if you need some 'extra goodies' either provided by JSF (as i18n in your example) or that need to be handled in the action method (as, for example, auditing/logging), you can employ JSF artifacts. But be aware, though, that you can use EL to access resource bundles directly in your views to translate text, as in i.e. `<label for="j_password">#{bundle.passwordName}: </label>`.

Comment: So if my post has `j_username` and `j_password` then everything is good?

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i did it:

```
<form action="${request.contextPath}/appLogin" method="POST">
     <h:form prependId="false">
         <p:inputText id="app_username" placeholder="Username" name="app_username" styleClass="Wid80 TexAlCenter Fs18" required="true"/>
         <p:password id="app_password" placeholder="Password" name="app_password"  label="Password" required="true" styleClass="Wid80 TexAlCenter Fs18"/>
         <button type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only Wid60">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Login</span>
         </button>      
     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>    
     </h:form>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

I'm using the Premium Theme Ronin from Primefaces and custom login URLs like "appLogin" and custom Parameters like "app_username".